# MongoDB iteration on aggregate

Tags: mongodb, loops, asynchronous, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection :

```
{  
  "value" : "20",
  "type" : "square",
  "name" : "form1"
},
{
  "value" : "24",
  "type" : "circle",
  "name" : "form2"
},
{
  "value" : "12",
  "type" : "square",
  "name" : "form3"
}
```

This aggregation :

```
let searchTerm = "form2"

db.myCollec.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "data": [
      { "$match": { "name": searchTerm  }},
      { "$project": { "name": 1, "type": 1, "_id": 0 }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.name", 0] }, searchTerm ]
    },
    "type": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.type", 0] }, null]
    }
  }}
])
```

give this result :

```
{ "name" : "form2", "type" : "circle" }
```

and if i'm looking for a non existing "form4" :

```
{ "name" : "form4", "type" : null }
```

Now I want to do it for a lot of values so I try to put them in an array then loop on this array. According to the asynchronous property of javascript I try this code :

```
tab = [ "form2", "form4" ] 
for( var i =0; i<(tab.length);i++) { (function (i) {
searchTerm = tab[i]
db.myCollec.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "data": [
      { "$match": { "name": searchTerm  }},
      { "$project": { "name": 1, "type": 1, "_id": 0 }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.name", 0] }, searchTerm ]
    },
    "type": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.type", 0] }, null]
    }
  }}
])
}) (i) }
```

There is no result...
If I add a `print(searchTerm)` the values are well printed but no result for the aggregation.

Thanx for your help.